# OpenGL repeating texture part

Tags: opengl

Normally I use texture coordinates from 0 to 1.

```
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
```

If I need texture part (clipping) I use -

```
glTexCoord2f(Texture.Left / Texture.Width, Texture.Top / Texture.Height);
glTexCoord2f(Texture.Right / Texture.Width, Texture.Top / Texture.Height);
glTexCoord2f(Texture.Right / Texture.Width, Texture.Bottom / Texture.Height);
glTexCoord2f(Texture.Left / Texture.Width, Texture.Bottom / Texture.Height);
```

If I need repeat texture A x B times I use -

```
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(A, 0);
glTexCoord2f(A, B);
glTexCoord2f(0, B);
```

Although if I need repeat only part of texture (clipping) this doesnt work -

```
glTexCoord2f(Texture.Left / Texture.Width * A, Texture.Top / Texture.Height * B);
glTexCoord2f(Texture.Right / Texture.Width * A, Texture.Top / Texture.Height * B);
glTexCoord2f(Texture.Right / Texture.Width * A, Texture.Bottom / Texture.Height * B);
glTexCoord2f(Texture.Left / Texture.Width * A, Texture.Bottom / Texture.Height * B);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to write a custom fragment shader to do texture repeat on a tile in the interior of a texture atlas.

Or move that tile to the edge(s) that you want repeated and use >1 and/or <0 texcoords as usual.